# How Do I Minus A Total From It's Next Highest Multiple Of 10

Tags: highest, chinese-remainder-theorem

So I have a total, say **24**, I need my code to find the nearest hightest multiple of **10**. This would be **30** of course, so I need the code to calculate **(30-24)**. If the number is **20** it would be **20** beucase it is equal to a highest muliple of **10**. I then need to store the result for later use.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def nh(val):
...   return 9 - ((val + 9) % 10)
... 
>>> nh(24)
6
>>> nh(20)
0
```

Comment: I don't fully understand

Comment: @MisterChief: You don't actually need to know exactly *what* the next highest value is, you just need to know how far along towards it you are.

Comment: This seems to work, But what is this calculating?                                  (gtin_total + 9) // 10 * 10 - gtin_total